# programmatically stream audio with NetStream

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, red5, flash-media-server

In Flex you can stream microphone audio to an FMS/Red5 server using [NetStream.attachAudio](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetStream.html#attachAudio%28%29), which requires a Microphone object.  Is it possible to stream audio through the NetStream from somewhere other than a Microphone?  For example, from a file/embedded resource?

The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to be able to run automated tests that don't require using an actual microphone.

Comment: are you specifically needing the NetStream object for your tests or can you just use a Sound object?

Comment: The test is to send audio up to FMS/Red5, which (as far as I understand it) needs a NetStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like this isn't possible.  My workaround is to use [SoundFlower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) to route audio file playback (invoked outside of Flash) into a virtual microphone, which Flash then streams to the media server.  From Flash's point of view, its just as if you were manually speaking into the mic.